# Excel VBA Power Query - How to create a query that dynamically returns only the sale's rows of the last minute?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, time, intervals

I have a comma separated csv file with the following structure:

Col Headers:

```
ProdDate,   ProdTime, OLEDATETIME, ProdBuyPrice, ProdSellPrice, ProdBoughtQTY, ProdSoldQTY, etc
09/21/2019, 13:54:22, 43729.5801,  12.45,        12.61,         8,          9, etc.
```

This CSV file is atualized many times per minute (5 to 70 times per minute) meaning that it can have 5 to 70 lines within the last minute of sales, then I can't fix an arbitray fixed number on "mantain first lines" to return only the rows that arrived in the last minute and I never did this before with Power Query. So I need an finished recipe to do this, but my googling resulted nothing until now.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post what you have already done

Comment: @Nelson Brockes ---- Could you be more specific about what you want to achieve? It is good to have a background story of what is already happening, which you have sort of wrote up above about the new Rows coming in 5 to 70 a minute... But now then could you create an list of bullet points of what you are trying to achieve in the desired order ... just like if you were doing it manually every time, and time was not a limiting factor...?

Comment: Hi @Andras Dorko,

Ok, I'll use another more familiar example. FOREX brokers provide various types of market data such as t1, m1, m5, m15, etc. Let's compare the t1 data with the m1 data. In the case of data m1 we have tables with the following structure:

Headers: Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
Line 1: 10:38:00, 1.101886, 1.101955, 1.101805, 1.101912, 5512
Line 2: 10:37:00, 1.101796, 1.101913, 1.101773, 1.101886, 5585

Note that in data table m1 each row corresponds to 1 minute.

Data table t1 has the following structure:

Comment: Headers: Time, Bid, Ask, BidSize, AskSize
Line 1: 10:37:03, 1.101896, 1.101922, 5056, 5055
Line 2: 10:37:02, 1.101895, 1.101918, 5055, 5054

Note that in the case of table t1 each row corresponds to 1 tick and that the table can receive more than 1 tick per second, so the number of rows to represent one minute is variable and depends on the speed of negotiations.

Comment: Well, in my case it's like I had only one table t1 and wanted to build a table m1 with the data from table t1. Knowing that normally the number of rows per minute from table t1 can range from 5 to 70, I could, for example, make a query by returning a fixed number of rows, say 75 or 80 rows, and find the opening values, high, low, close and volume corresponding to 1 minute and thus build a table m1.

Comment: But besides this is not an elegant solution, I would always have to return 75 or 80 lines per cycle even if market movement was slow at 5 lines per minute and this would have an impact on speed increasing the time required for each cycle. cycle.

So what I want is to use Power Query to make a dynamic query that returns to the spreadsheet just the number of rows belonging to the last minute, none more, none less.

If I get a query that does this with a FOREX t1 table, it will do the same with my tables as well.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hello @StefanG

I think I've clarified the question enough in my answer to Andras Dorko. Please read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how you can identify a dynamic row number.  In this example, we have a table that shows fruit sales by store.  We want to create a query that returns the highest number of bananas sold.

This is what our data table looks like.

[image]

**Step 1 - Add an index column starting from 1.  This assigns row numbers.**
Add Column > Index Column > From 1

**Step 2 - Filter and Sort the data.**

Remove any columns that are unnecessary.

Filter the Item column for Bananas.

Sort the Values column in descending order.

Right-click on the first value in the Index column and choose Drill-Down.

[image]

**RESULT** 
Now you have a dynamic row #.  You could also instead choose the value itself to return the sales instead of the index.  To apply this to other scenarios, just keep filtering and sorting until you get to the result you need.

[image]

**This is how you filter a time column for records occurring in the latest one minute of times.**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="t_DatesAndTimes"]}[Content],
    ChangedTypes_ColData = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}}),
    AddCol_DateAndTime = Table.AddColumn(ChangedTypes_ColData, "Date and Time", each [Date] & [Time], type datetime),
    LatestTime_ofReport_MinusOneMinute = List.Max(AddCol_DateAndTime[Date and Time])-#duration(0,0,1,0),
    FilterRows_KeepTimesInLastMinute = Table.SelectRows(AddCol_DateAndTime, each [Date and Time] >= LatestTime_ofReport_MinusOneMinute)
in
    FilterRows_KeepTimesInLastMinute
```

**Data Table needing to be filtered**

[image: Table to filter based on time]

**Table filtered for time in the last minute of times listed in the report.**

[image: Filtered Table]

Comment: Thanks for spending your time trying to help me, Jenn. But except for a slight sarcasm (just in one of my parallel interpretations) that made me laugh a little, your suggestion didn't work, perhaps, for lack of a time's column. Note that my primary goal is to automatically filter only transactions occurring in the LAST MINUTE. Best regards.

Comment: Glad to help. I left the answer relative because the question read as though the request was how to return a dynamic row count and also did not specify how the last minute is defined.  Is it the latest 60 seconds of the date or the latest 60 relative to the latest transaction of the report?  Please clarify how the last 60 seconds should be defined.

Comment: Well, although your answer didn't exactly match what I expected (a routine that shows only the last minute lines starting at zero seconds ahead - maybe I didn't explain this point well), you helped me a lot because ordering a query At exactly 58 seconds of the last minute I can take a "snapshot" of the last minute and that already satisfies me!

Comment: Although sometimes one or two lines appear before zero seconds of the last minute, I can take out this burr with VBA or some formulas inside cells until I learn enough M language to make a query that shows only the last minute lines starting at zero seconds ahead!

Comment: Thanks so much Jenn! You helped me a lot! If you happen to have any questions that you think I can help you with, not exactly about programing, please feel free to contact me via Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/brockes

Comment: Glad to help.  For your seconds issue - I recommend playing around with the time rounding before the filter is applied, to see if you can narrow to the exact dataset you are looking to return.